# Filling the arrays with different data type by 1 function

Tags: c, function, types

I have to fill the 2 arrays of int and double using function.

So, i make 2 almost the same functions, which differ only by data type.

```
void fill_double(double* arr,int n)  
{                                    
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%lf",&arr[i]);
  }
}

void fill_int(int* arr,int n)  
{                             
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Q:How to make 1 general function to fill either int and double arrays ?

Comment: Not possible in C. In C++, [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) exist to solve this very problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { Integer, Double } type;

void fill(type type, void *array, int size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(type == Integer)
            scanf("%d", ((int*)array) + i);
        else
            scanf("%lf", ((double*)array) + i);
    }
}
int main(void){
    double dd[3];
    int    id[3];
    int    i;

    fill(Double, dd, 3);
    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        printf("%f\n", dd[i]);

    fill(Integer, id, 3);
    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        printf("%d\n", id[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

macro version

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { _int, _double };
#define type(x) _##x

#define FILL(T, A, S) do{ char *table[] = {"%d", "%lf" };int i; for(i=0;i<S;++i){scanf(table[type(T)], &A[i]);}}while(0)

int main(void){
    double dd[3];
    int    id[3];
    int    i;

    FILL(double, dd, 3);
    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        printf("%f\n", dd[i]);

    FILL(int, id, 3);
    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        printf("%d\n", id[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to `qsort` in the standard library, you'll need to pass the size in bytes of the elements as well as the size of the array. This version returns an `int` like `scanf`: the number of elements scanned if successful, otherwise an error code.

```
int fill_array(void *array, size_t size, size_t count, const char*fmt) {
    size_t i;
    char *p = array;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int conv = scanf(fmt, p + i * size);
        if (conv != 1) return conv;
    }
    return (int)count;
}
```

You might macro-ize it, to avoid passing the element size.

```
#define FILL_ARRAY(a, count, fmt) \
    do{\
        fill_array((a), sizeof((a)[0]), (count), (fmt));\
    } while(0)
```

Comment: Could you write an example of filling an array by 1st method ?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could try to do something like this is with macros.  Granted, this is not a general, or necessarily even a great solution, but you could do something like this:

```
#define MAKE_FILL_TEMPLATE(type, scan)   \
    void fill_##type(type *arr, int n) { \
        int i;                           \
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {        \
            scanf(scan, &arr[i]);        \
        }                                \
     }

MAKE_FILL_TEMPLATE(int, "%d")
MAKE_FILL_TEMPLATE(double, "%lf")
```

And now the macro template will define the function for you.

That being said, this is usually frowned upon as it's difficult for a reader to follow and debug.